# Excel indirect drop down list working in 1st row only

Tags: excel, dropdown

Am experience a similar challenge. The dropdown list works for the first row were the validation formulas were created but not for other rows below. Please see attached photo for your support.
[image: Dropdown working only in 1st row]
Thank

Tried copying the cells where I created the indifference drop down but not working

Answer (score 1):

`=INDIRECT($A$3)` is an Absolute Reference.  It will *always* look at the cell in the Third Row of Column A.  Even if you drag it down, or across, it will always look at the same cell — it is fixed, permanent, and *absolute*.

If you want to be able to copy the cell to the next row down, you will need to change at least the Row reference to be *Relative*.  What this means is, you drop the `$` symbol:

```
=INDIRECT($A3)
```

This will **always** look in Column A, but copying to a different cell will change the *Row* that it looks at.  (This makes it a "mixed" reference.  `A$3` would be a "mixed" reference with a fixed Row, where the column changed.  `A3` would be a "relative" reference, where *both* the Row and Column changed when you copied it to another cell)

For more information, please see the article "[Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)" on the Microsoft support site